# Invoking a method or sending callback without destroying gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to send a callback between two MonoBehaviour Classes. I chose singleton to do so. Following is my code

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Main instance = null;
    public GameObject player;
    private Main()
    {
    }

    public static Main Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance==null)
            {
                instance = new Main();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void onReceive()
    {
        //hide the gameobject on receiving notification.
        player.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

I use the following code to invoke `onReceive` from another MonoBehaviour class

```
Main.Instance.onReceive();
```

I have of course hooked the player to the unity Gameobject. Unfortunately, it is null when I do so using singleton. How do  I pass information to the MonoBehavour class without getting the GameObject getting destroyed?

Comment: passing details never kills the game object unless you write to destroy it

Comment: but it never hides the gameobject though the activate method gets invoked. :(

Comment: I tried to hide the player though a button and Im able to do so. but Im not able to do so through singleton. :(

Comment: probably because player has no value?

Comment: No value? Could you please explain?

Comment: well you never set a value for player.. you also only set the instance details when calling that static method if one already existed in the scene it wouldnt be the core instance.. this is not how you do singletons

Comment: If I remember correctly you shouldn't use constructors with Monobehaviour classes, you can try to make it normal class and still get your job done, but I think Monobehaviour is calling the constructors, so you have to interact with your class with Start or Awake...
Basicly remove monobehaviour inheritance, and assign player Gameobject throught code after you create your instance in the get operator